# Why is the JaCoCo .exec file generated for Android off-device tests almost empty if testCoverageEnabled is true, but only for library modules?

Tags: android, jacoco, android-jacoco

I'm working in a multi-module Android project with an application module and a library module. If I simply add

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco {
     toolVersion '0.8.7'
}
```

to the `build.gradle` for each module, then when I run the off-device unit tests from the command line in each module's directory, I see an .exec file created at `build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec` with a size of ~27k or so. Generating a report from this does what I'd expect.

If I add

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

to the build.gradle for each module (so that I can later gather coverage numbers for on-device tests as well) then when I run the off-device unit tests the .exec file is instead created in `build/outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec`.

More importantly, while that file is still ~27k when I'm running the tests in the application module, it is almost empty (only 45 bytes) when I'm running the tests in a library module in the same project.

Is there a reason testCoverageEnabled interferes with off-device code coverage for library modules but not for the primary application module?

Comment: Are you using gradle 7.0 ? If so, check out https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195860510.

I have a library project too and was facing issues with empty exec file with gradle 7.0. It was working fine in gradle 4.0.2.. 

The work around with `testCoverageEnabled false` worked with gradle 7.0 and my coverage for my library is fine now.